# Sub bot generation in discord.py

Tags: python, discord

Is it possible to make a bot using discord.py which can temporarily create new sub-bots and then delete them?

I cant find anything in the documentation. Is there something I'm overlooking, is it possible to implement with a workaround, or was discord.py not meant to be used like this?

Comment: I do not think you can do that.

Comment: I don't think you can connect Bots to each other, although that certainly would be cool.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do that but you can use the webhook system to create a "bot" which then you can delete. It looks exactly like an unverified bot and is what bots like emoji.gg use

Comment: Can you please provide some documentation or link to code that supports your answer?